# Error while starting Discovery service

Tags: discovery-service

I get the stack trace below when running start.ps1 to start the Discovery service in the powershell. The database is running on my local MSSQLSERVER instance which I have confirmed is on port 1433.

My storage configuration looks like this:

```
<Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" 
         Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="10" 
          MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <Property Name="serverName" Value="(local)" />
        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_DiscoveryService"/>
        <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser" />
        <Property Name="password" Value="It's a secret" />
    </DataSource>
</Storage>
```

I can connect to the database and execute SQL from a Powershell script that uses the same values as in the properties of the data source.

The exception seems to be telling me that there is a problem making a connection to the database. Having checked the basic details, I am now looking for suggestions as to what else might cause this failure.

Here is the stack trace:

> java.exe : Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with
>    name 'dataSourceFactoryImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.bean
>   s.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.List com.sdl.odata.processor.datasource.fa
>   ctory.DataSourceFactoryImpl.dataSourceProviders; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExce
>   ption: Error creating bean with name 'tridionConfigDataSourceProvider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nes
>   ted exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sdl.web
>   .discovery.datalayer.TridionConfigDataSource com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.TridionConfigDataSourceProvider.dataSource
>   ; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tridionCo
>   nfigDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibe
>   rnate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
>   At C:\SDLWebCDServices\Discovery\bin\start.ps1:42 char:5
>   +     & $java_run $jvmoptions -cp $classpath $className $arguments
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Exception in th...open connection:String) [], RemoteException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError 
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(Auto
>   wiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapabl
>   eBeanFactory.java:1210)
>       at 
>   ===================== Lots more lines of stack trace... removed for clarity =====================
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
>       ... 54 more
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host (local), port 1433 has fa
>   iled. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host a
>   nd accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."
>   .
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.j
>   ava:242)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2280)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:493)
>       at 
>   ============================= More trimmed here

Comment: Try replacing (local) with localhost. I think it may be a window-ism that java doesn't want to know about.

Comment: Thanks Quirijn. I'd already considered this, but still worth checking. It turns out that with (local) I see the stack trace after a timeout of about 50 seconds. With localhost, it appears never to timeout. The script just hangs.

Comment: I tried within a working environment changing to "(local)" and gives me the same error. Try with localhost or the hostname, to achieve the database connection, and check the cd_core logs of the discovery service

Comment: I've just realised that start.ps1 doesn't give any feedback when the service starts, so when I said "The script just hangs", what was actually happening  was that Quirijn was right. Raul also deserves a credit for making me look again. Thanks guys... Quirijn - if you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution, as suggested by Quirijn and Raúl, was to replace the string `(local)` in the serverName property with the machine name.

I've just checked my 2013 server to confirm that I have used `(local)` in my storage configs there without any problems. It seems this is a new "gotcha".

Comment: I always use "localhost" so I know for sure that works.